# Javascript Regexp dynamic generation from variables?

Tags: javascript, regex, dynamic

How to construct two regex patterns into one?

For example I have one long pattern and one smaller, I need to put smaller one in front of long one.

```
var pattern1 = ':\(|:=\(|:-\(';
var pattern2 = ':\(|:=\(|:-\(|:\(|:=\(|:-\('
str.match('/'+pattern1+'|'+pattern2+'/gi');
```

This doesn't work. When I'm concatenating strings, all slashes are gone.

Answer (score 286, accepted):

You have to use [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/regexp):

```
str.match(new RegExp(pattern1+'|'+pattern2, 'gi'));
```

---

> When I'm concatenating strings, all slashes are gone.

If you have a backslash in your pattern to escape a special regex character, (like `\(`), you have to use **two** backslashes in the string (because `\` is the escape character in a string): `new RegExp('\\(')` would be the same as `/\(/`.

So your patterns have to become:

```
var pattern1 = ':\\(|:=\\(|:-\\(';
var pattern2 = ':\\(|:=\\(|:-\\(|:\\(|:=\\(|:-\\(';
```

Answer (score 35):

Use the below:

```
var regEx = new RegExp(pattern1+'|'+pattern2, 'gi');

str.match(regEx);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `'/'` be removed when using `new RegExp(...)`?

Comment: @BartKiers great point! Common mistake ! x) It would be worth adding a big notice somewhere :)

Answer (score 21):

You have to forgo the regex literal and use the object constructor, where you can pass the regex as a string.

```
var regex = new RegExp(pattern1+'|'+pattern2, 'gi');
str.match(regex);
```

Answer (score 4):

The RegExp constructor creates a regular expression object for matching text with a pattern.

```
    var pattern1 = ':\\(|:=\\(|:-\\(';
    var pattern2 = ':\\(|:=\\(|:-\\(|:\\(|:=\\(|:-\\(';
    var regex = new RegExp(pattern1 + '|' + pattern2, 'gi');
    str.match(regex);
```

Above code works perfectly for me...