# Javascript RegExp: Create regex with variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript Regexp dynamic generation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090103/javascript-regexp-dynamic-generation)

I am trying to create a new RegExp with a variable; however, I do not know the sytax to do this. Any help would be great!

I need to change this: **(v.name.search(new RegExp(/Josh Gonzalez/i)) != -1)** change it to this: **(v.name.search(new RegExp(/q/i)) != -1)**. I basically need to replace the "josh" with the **variable q ~ var q = $( 'input[name="q"]' ).val();**

Thanks for the help

```
$( 'form#search-connections' )
    .submit( function( event )
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        var q = $( 'input[name="q"]' ).val();

        console.log( _json );

        $.each( _json, function(i, v) {

        //NEED TO INSERT Q FOR JOSH 

            if (v.name.search(new RegExp(/Josh Gonzalez/i)) != -1) {

                alert(v.name);
                return;
            }
        });         
    }
);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like so:

```
new RegExp(q + " Gonzalez", "i");
```

Using the `/` characters is how to define a RegExp with RegExp literal syntax.  To create a RegExp from a string, pass the string to the RegExp constructor.  These are equivalent:

```
var expr = /Josh Gonzalez/i;
var expr = new RegExp("Josh Gonzalez", "i");
```

The way you have it you are passing a regular expression to the regular expression constructor... it's redundant.

Comment: Hmmm.  When I first posted my answer, your answer didn't have the same code as my answer (thus why I posted) and now you do.  Interesting...

Comment: Ya, I usually edit my answers a few times in the first couple of minutes after I first post.  Post, re-read question, double-check answer, make corrections, repeat until I'm satisfied.  I don't want to be too slow, but I also want to be accurate.  You must've seen my original post before I got my edits in.

Comment: This worked great! Here is the finally code:

   var q  = $( 'input[name="q"]' ).val(),
   r   = new RegExp( q, 'i');
   
   $.each( _json, function(i, v) {
    
          if (v.name.search(r) != -1) {
              
     alert(v.name);
              return;
          }
      });

Answer (score 1):

You just need to build the string you want using string addition and pass it to the RegExp constructor like this:

```
var q = $( 'input[name="q"]' ).val();
var re = new RegExp(q + " Gonzalez", "i");
if (v.name.search(re) != -1) {
    // do your stuff here
}
```