# Why does my RegExp() not work with my contains()?

Tags: jquery, regex, list, contains

When removing a list item based on the browsers width I can do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var changeWidth = 992;
    if ($(window).width() < changeWidth) {
        $('li:contains("Home")').remove();
    }
});
```

When researching for a way to remove `Home` with a typical regex pattern similar to `Home|HOME` I did a search and learned about [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) so I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var changeWidth = 992,
        regex = new RegExp('Home|HOME');

    if ($(window).width() < changeWidth) {
        $('li:contains("' + regex + '")').remove();
    }
});
```

it didn't work so I researched and found [Javascript RegExp: Create regex with variable [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829523/javascript-regexp-create-regex-with-variable) and tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var changeWidth = 992,
        regex = new RegExp("Home", "i");

    if ($(window).width() < changeWidth) {
        $('li:contains("' + regex + '")').remove();
    }
});
```

after that didn't work I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5090166/1952287) and tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var changeWidth = 992,
        pattern1 = "Home",
        pattern2 = "HOME",
        regex = new RegExp(pattern1+'|'+pattern2, 'gi');

    if ($(window).width() < changeWidth) {
        $('li:contains("' + regex + '")').remove();
    }
});
```

After doing further reading from:

- [Javascript Regexp dynamic generation from variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090103/javascript-regexp-dynamic-generation-from-variables)
- [How to pass a variable into regex in jQuery/Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1695633/how-to-pass-a-variable-into-regex-in-jquery-javascript)
- [Use regex to match a value in form input](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/use-regex-to-match-a-value-in-form-input)

I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var changeWidth = 992,
        string = "Home",
        regex = new RegExp("HOME", 'gi'),
        result = string.match(regex);

    if ($(window).width() < changeWidth) {
        $('li:contains("' + result + '")').remove();
    }
});
```

it works if `Home` is present but not when `HOME` is present.  What am I doing wrong and how can I regex for `Home` and `HOME`?

Comment: Are you sure `contains` accepts a regex?