# using variable in jquery, javascript regexp

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

How to use variables inside regexp(to check the existence of a substring ) taking in consideration the following example

```
var hash = '!price=475;1500&ram=475;1275';
var uri_params = ['price', 'display', 'ram', 'hdd', 'brand'];
$.each(uri_params,function(index, param){
            console.log(param);
            if(/( !param(.*)|&param(.*))/i.test(hash)){
                 console.log('test');
                //than here I should add the new value to matched param

            }
});
```

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/lgtsfiddler/c936b/8/

Comment: `if(hash.match(new RegExp('!' + param + '(.*)|&' + param + '(.*)'))`

Comment: yepp this works. thanks a lot!! Please post as answer to can accept

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Regexp dynamic generation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090103/javascript-regexp-dynamic-generation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will work for parameters in RegExp.

`if(hash.match(new RegExp('!' + param + '(.*)|&' + param + '(.*)'))`