# Javascript: String.match() - pass string variable in regular expression

Tags: javascript, string

I tried to rewrite the method (part of [tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_match_regexp2) on w3schools).

The problem is to make a variable string to become part of the regular expression.

**Tutorial Sample code:**

```
function myFunction() {
    var str = "The rain in SPAIN stays mainly in the plain"; 
    var res = str.match(/ain/gi);
    console.log(res)
}
```

**I tried:**

```
function myFunction() {
    var str = "The rain in SPAIN stays mainly in the plain"; 
    var test = "ain";
    var re = "/"+test+"/gi";
    var res = str.match(re);
    console.log(res);
}
```

The way I tried did not work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the regex constructor, like:

```
function myFunction() {
    var str = "The rain in SPAIN stays mainly in the plain",
        test = "ain",
        re = new RegExp(test, 'gi'),
        res = str.match(re);

    console.log(res);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to use `RegExp` constructor if you want to pass a value of variable as regex.

```
var test = "ain";
var re = new RegExp(test, "gi");
```

If your variable contains special chars, it's better to escape those.

```
var re = new RegExp(test.replace(/(\W)/g, "\\$1"), "gi");
```

Answer (score 6):

Note that you pass a string to `match`. If we follow the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), this will do a `new RegExp(test)`. So you should avoid `/` and `/gi` strings and add corresponding flags to the RegExp constructor: the default constructor doesn't add neither global search (`g`) nor case insensitive search (`i`).

So the solution to your problem:

```
var str = "The rain in SPAIN stays mainly in the plain"; 
var test = "ain";
var res = str.match(new RegExp(test, "gi"));
```

This will returns :

```
Array [ "ain", "AIN", "ain", "ain" ]
```

Note :

The form `str.match(test, "gi");` works only in Firefox browser but is deprecated and throws a console warning from Firefox 39 (see RGraham comment).

Comment: This won't pass the `gi` flags to the `RegExp` constructor, according to the linked docs. It passes `g` by default, but not `i`

Comment: @RGraham this is the reason why I pass `"gi"` to `str.match`. If we do not pass it, the result is just `Array [ "ain" ]` : no global search and no case insensitive search. So I would say by default nothing is passed to the `RegExp` constructor.

Comment: There is no overload for `String.prototype.match` which accepts 2 arguments. At least in the spec & in Chrome implementation. Your code results in `Array [ "ain" ]` on Chrome 42

Comment: Good point. I tested in FF 31 and the overload is present and the result is the one I provided. I will update my answer.

Comment: Yeah, this is mentioned in the [Firefox-specific notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Firefox-specific_notes) on MDN, but a warning only appears on FF39 onwards

Answer (score 5):

Yes `match()` not works with string literals

You can use `var re = new RegExp(test,"gi");`

```
 var str = "The rain in SPAIN stays mainly in the plain"; 
    var test = "ain";
    var re = new RegExp(test,"gi");
    var res = str.match(re);
    console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 5):

You could have searched for "dynamic regular expressions" and you would have found:
[Javascript Regexp dynamic generation from variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090103/javascript-regexp-dynamic-generation-from-variables)
or [Use dynamic (variable) string as regex pattern in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885855/use-dynamic-variable-string-as-regex-pattern-in-javascript) which both describe it very well.

Comment: That really should be a comment, not an answer. Or perhaps this question should be marked as a duplicate of one of the linked answers?

Comment: I have no idea how this could be done. If you tell me, I will do so for the next duplicates that I see. But most of the times when I saw other duplicates, people responded as "answer" as it was the answer to the problem.

Comment: @eX0du5 You may have seen it, but that's not how it works :) If you have enough rep, you can see a "Close" option. If you don't, leave a comment explaining it's a duplicate & someone with enough rep will vote to close for you