# JS Regex dynamic generation from variables

Tags: javascript

How do you use a variable in a regular expression? in this case :

```
var string = "How are you doing today? You are such a nice person!";
var count =  string.match(/\bare\b/g).length; 
alert(count);// 'are'=>2
```

Edit my:

```
var string = "How are you doing today? You are such a nice person!";
var text = 'are';
var count =  string.match(new RegExp('/\b'+text+'\b/g')); 
count = count? count.length : 0;  //checking if there are matches or  not.
alert(count); => Not working
```

Comment: Where is your variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use a variable in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the regular expression pattern in a variable and then use `new RegExp()` with that variable that has the pattern. And don't use `g` as a part of the pattern, pass it as a second argument of `RegExp()` instead.

```js
var string = "How are you doing today? You are such a nice person!";
var text = 'are';
var regEx = '\\b'+text+'\\b';
var count =  string.match(new RegExp(regEx,"g")).length;
alert(count);
```

Comment: Typing in this question's title into a new question automatically links him to all sorts of topics with this answer already, he is just blatantly wasting everyone's time.

Comment: @ASDFGerte might be but I think OP is confused because he added `/g` in the first argument instead of second argument in `RegExp`

Comment: Thanks you very much

Comment: @TranBa glad to help you

Comment: The first suggested duplicate is ["Javascript Regexp dynamic generation from variables?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090103/javascript-regexp-dynamic-generation-from-variables) (almost identical name) which has an accepted top answer that has `gi` mode. No. Just no.

Comment: ```regexp: {
                         regexp : /"^([\w-\.]+)@ domainName"/,
                         message: 'The domain name is wrong and your domain name is: ' + domainName
                     }```. I have regExp like above. Here domainName is variable. I displayed domainName in the message which displayed in GUI. I have read some answer. but I could not make it work since I am new to regExp. @Ankit Agarwal Can you tell me how to pass parameter?