# I want to highlight the Specific word in my ajax response loop

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I want to highlight the word which user has searched. I am getting an array in response which will shows the occurrence of that word.
I want to highlight that word inside my array which I received.

```
 success:function(response){
                     console.log(response); 
                      $("#h5data").append(sessionStorage.getItem("word"));
                      $("#WC").append(response.doc.count);

                      $.each(response.doc.occurrence, function (key, value) {  
          $('#exampleid').append("<tr>\
                <td>"+key+"</td>\
                <td>"+value+"</td>\
                </tr>");


        });
```

This is my ajax response which is showing the occurrence but now I have to highlight the word which user has searched.

Comment: In other words, you have a string of text and you want to highlight a word or words (possibly using a <span>). I'll bet there are existing solutions for that; did you look for these? When looking for existing answers, you need to ditch all irrelevant stuff (i.e. ajax, loop)

Comment: A quick way is to do `text.split(searchTerm).join('<span>' + searchTerm + '<span>')` and use CSS to highlight the text inside the spans.

Comment: No its  user has types a word and then my api returns an array of occurrences of those words.

Comment: So I want to highlight word inside that array which I receive in response.

Comment: What are these occurrences? Sentences?

Comment: yes array of sentences it returns sentences which have that word in it

Comment: Exactly. So ignore the array for a second, and think of the first sentence. Now look at my first comment again. I told you that the fact that you have multiple sentences or the fact that you've loaded them via ajax does not matter at all.

Comment: Here's example code: https://jsfiddle.net/pc4jx593/

Comment: Before posting here, you need to look for existing solutions. And you will only find them if you narrow down the actual problem you have, and remove all the irrelevant stuff.  If you google "js highlight word in sentence" you will get [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49893360/highlight-all-word-matches-of-sentence-of-text-javascript) as first result